# What can explain the gradual increase of transfer speed at the beginning of a file transfer?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I transfer a 4 GB file from my internal disk to an external hard drive on Windows 10. What can explain the gradual increase of transfer speed at the beginning?

[image]

Comment: The cache fills up and then writes come from reading from the cache versus the reading from the drive itself. Are you having a problem here or are you mainly curious about what you are seeing happening here?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks, just curious about what I'm seeing happening here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 `Fills up the cache` does not really explain why it fills up slower at the beginning though. I'd say it's more likely related to the spinning / waking up of the source (or even, destination) drive, or less likely, the "waking up" of the CPU (probably a bad way to put it; I guess I should say "clocking up"?).

Comment: This is fairly standard behavior IMO. I did a little research and had trouble finding the exact mechanism but both TCP and SMB have flow control features to find a stable bandwidth. When the file transfer starts, neither the client nor server know how much bandwidth is available. Through these flow control mechanisms a healthy transfer speed is reached and it takes a period of time for the speed to stabilize as the two ends establish a stable transfer rate. Otherwise you would see the speed all over the place due to packet loss, buffer issues, etc.